# What are some very simple CSS frameworks?

Tags: html, css

What are some very simple CSS frameworks / design packages?

- I don't need the added complexity of a combined HTML, CSS, and JS framework.
- I will be creating only a few general page layouts for this site.
- I'm building the site on TinyMVC.
- I want very minimalistic design (mostly black text on a white background).
- I'm planning only one and two column layouts.
- I need tables, forms, lists, and other "basic elements" (use your best judgement).

  ***I wouldn't mind CSS3 with HTML5 in mind.*

EDIT#1:

- I need a grid system.
- I need a CSS reset.

Comment: What is it that you need that makes you look for a CSS framework?

Comment: “I need tables, forms, lists, and other "basic elements"” — that doesn’t sound like a framework (i.e. something which encapsulates relatively complex code), that sounds like a design (i.e. a set of decisions about what content should look like).

Comment: yeah, framework is not the right term for what i'm looking for.  Design reset with a grid (added some requirements to the post).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [960 Grid](http://960.gs/) and [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).

Both were great and both were very similar to each other.

I chose Blueprint because it satisfied my requirements the best and gave the simplest and cleanest appearance out of the box, with settings that I'ev barely had to touch for my site.

960 Grid would probably appeal to many people also.

They are both so easy to test, that I suggest trying both, and choosing the one after playing with them for 15 minutes each.

Answer (score 1):

I made my last website with compass and 960 grid system. I was very happy with the speed and results. With compass you have a reset and much more. (a lot of css3 mixins like border radius and gradients etc)

Check it out:

http://960.gs/

http://compass-style.org/

an intro into compass

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/88-intro-to-compass-sass/

here are some nice 960 grid sketches to help you designing your webpage in the 960 grid system

https://github.com/nathansmith/960-Grid-System/raw/master/sketch_sheets/960_sketch.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Variable Grid System](http://grids.heroku.com/) might be for you. I used it for some of my projects and it works. Not sure if I'm so much a grid system user, though. It usually gives you much more flexibility than you'll need/use. The cost of that is unnecessary CSS code size.

Comment: this is great if all you are looking for is an underlying grid for your site.  i wanted a little more foundational css.  i'll keep this in mind for the future though.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [**Cascade Framework Light**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframeworklight/). It's only 2Kb large, has excellent browser support and should have enough features to fit your needs.